# Chromium "Show in Folder" opens in text editor

Tags: gnome, nautilus, chromium

When I try and open a file I downloaded in Chromium, it opens in a text editor. (Geany)
I click on the arrow in the download bar and select "Show in folder".

I'm using Chromium daily stable and ubuntu 11.04 (although this was a problem previously under ubuntu 10.10) with Gnome.

I'm not sure where the breakdown is happening. In Chromium, ubuntu or maybe Geany has taken something hostage. Anyone having a similar problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's pretty weird and annoying.  I hope I can help you a bit into the correct direction :-)

Does it happen with any file type? txt? torrent? mp3?

- In `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` there is a list of files to be opened by an application. Have a look with `more ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and check if you can find something weird here.
- There is a nifty command, `mimeopen`, that allows you to alter what program should open what file  (and that updates the file I mentioned before). It will "guess" what would be the most logical option based on the file you feed it.

Examples:

```
$ mimeopen -d /home/{your_name}/Documents
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Open Folder  (nautilus-folder-handler)
    2) Other...

$ mimeopen -d \[Mazui\]_Ore_No_Imouto_-_14_\[SD\]\[7EA51F50\].mkv 
Please choose a default application for files of type video/x-matroska

    1) Enqueue in SMPlayer  (smplayer_enqueue)
    2) Movie Player  (totem)
    3) SMPlayer  (smplayer)
    4) Banshee  (banshee)
    5) VLC media player  (vlc)
    6) Other...
```

If it is a problem regarding mimetypes, this should solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I looked in mimeapps.list and found this line: inode/directory=geany.desktop;jedit.desktop;
After commenting it out, things returned to normal. Thanks!

Comment: That *is* a nifty command. I like it.

Comment: I have this problem but this command did not help.  I was able to change the default but the application that's actually opening was not even the list

Comment: `mimeopen` did the trick, however I found it funny that I couldn't find anything weird on the mimeapps.list files I found.  I did `for f in $(locate mimeapps.list); do sudo egrep "(inode)|(code\.desktop)" $f && echo "-> $f" ; done` but nothing stood out. However, after the problem was solved by using `mimeopen`, I ran the one liner again and it turned out `~/.config/mimeapps.list` had been updated with the option I selected. I guess the problem was no option for inode/directory was set. Anyway +1. This helped me a lot, I was going crazy.