# Files lens and xdg-open only open nautilus but not the correct applicatiion

Tags: unity, nautilus, nautilus-elementary, lenses, xdg-open

since some days my Files lens opens only nautilus but not the correct application which is associated with the file extension. 
For example, if I choose a PDF file, Nautilus is openend, pointing to the directory there the file is (and the file is selected) but Adobe Reader is not opened.

Then I do the same in the terminal with

```
xdg-open sample.pdf
```

only Nautilus is opened too.

xdg-mime shows me this info:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
acroread.desktop
```

The /usr/share/applications/acroread.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Adobe Reader 9
MimeType=application/pdf;application/vnd.fdf;application/vnd.adobe.pdx;application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml;application/vnd.adobe.xfdf;
Exec=acroread 
Type=Application
GenericName=PDF Viewer
Terminal=false
Icon=AdobeReader9
Caption=PDF Viewer
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
Categories=Application;Office;Viewer;X-Red-Hat-Base;
InitialPreference=9
```

The same with other file types like images, music files and office documents.

Then I doubleclick the file in Nautilus everything is ok and the correct applications are opened.

I assume this behaviour has something to do with Thunar which I've installed some days ago but deinstalled after these problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gnome-open to open pdf files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35602/using-gnome-open-to-open-pdf-files)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed xfce  (my question can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51008/web-browser-downloads-only-open-target-folders-cannot-open-files)).

My problem was solved after uninstalling all xubuntu*, xfdesktop4* and xfce4* packages (and thunar).

Perhaps you should start by typing:

`aptitude search xfce xfd xubuntu | grep ^i`

in order to see which packages are installed in your system.

Then proceed with their uninstallation.

Comment: Pavlos, thank you, this is the solution. Awful, that the deinstallation of Thunar don't remove all dependencys, which are installed due of it.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked ;)
I agree that it's kind of messy though...

Comment: This bug still happens in 12.04. :(

Comment: I could track it down to the 'exo-utils' package, where I probably have used `exo-preferred-applications` from once.
In ~/.local/share/applications there is the following entry, which appears to cause it, if exo-file-manager is installed: "mimeapps.list:x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop"

Comment: Ran into this issue on a system that had been originally installed using the xfce-based `mythbuntu` distro CD.  Uninstalling the xfce related packages worked.  If it still doesn't work, try [manually setting the default browser](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open#Set_the_default_browser)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the files-lens as well as in Chrome browser. I removed all xfce4 related packages and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

This is what I did,

```
sudo aptitude purge xfce4 desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2 orage tango-icon-theme thunar thunar-data thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4 xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-utils xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xfwm4-themes
```

I found this information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59640/how-can-i-completely-remove-xfce4-when-apt-get-remove-purge-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in exo-utils / exo-file-manager.desktop:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/exo/+bug/956255

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, but one way of solving (working-around) the problem is to make your own version of `xdg-open`:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cp /usr/bin/xdg-open ~/bin
```

You will need to make sure you have `~/bin` added to your path.  Your `~/.bashrc` file should contain something like the following in it (it may already be there):

```
if [ -d ~/bin ]; then
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
fi
```

Now you need to edit `~/bin/xdg-open` and add the following line *after* the line which only contains the text `detectDE` in it (around line 525 in my version of the script):

```
DE=xfce
```

After logging out and back in, documents should open with their associated handlers, instead of with Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

I solved deleting (or commenting with a #) this line from file  **~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list**:

```
x-scheme-handler/file=nautilus.desktop
```