# Why removing the xfce4 package doesn't remove the XFCE desktop environment?

Tags: apt

I wanted a window manager, so I installed xfce4. I used

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

to do this. To remove it, I used

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xfce4
```

which didn't work, and neither did

```
sudo dpkg purge xfce4
```

as evidenced 1) `startx` launches the xfce desktop, and 2) `apt-cache search xfce4` returns a long list of installed packages.

So, how can I get rid of xfce4 and it's dependencies?

Comment: `apt-cache search` doesn't just show what packages are installed. It also show what packages *can* be installed in the future.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`xfce4` itself is a meta-package that will install a default configured xfce desktop environment.

In most cases the base files that comes with xfce4 are: xfconf, xfce4-utils, xfwm4, xfce4-session, thunar, xfdesktop4, exo-utils

So you can do

```
sudo apt-get purge xfconf xfce4-utils xfwm4 xfce4-session thunar xfdesktop4 exo-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-terminal
```

Then most of the package that were associated with these package become autoremovable so you can run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

or, almost all xfce4 package depend upon `libxfce4util-common`. Just purge that one and you remove everything related to `xfce`

Answer (score 8):

Note that `apt-cache` is not showing you *installed* packages, but rather those which are known about.

To test what you have installed, you might like to use:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep xfce
```

Be sure to look at the second output column to see whether it's installed or deinstalled.

After purging all xfce packages, the above command returns no output on my machine.

Answer (score 7):

Aptitude can do this by using package search ~n and using -P to prompt when adding or removing packages.

```
sudo aptitude -P remove ~nxfce4
```

Substitute remove with purge if you would like to remove the system configuration files:

```
sudo aptitude -P purge ~nxfce4
```

To remove user config files (use -r with care - recursive delete!!):

```
sudo rm -r ~/.config/xfce4
```

Comment: Worthy to mention that cleaned up all xfce4 trace just leaving gtk2-engines-xfce & xfce-keyboard-shortcuts on Raspbian Jessie Lite

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo aptitude purge xfce4 desktop-base exo-utils gtk2-engines-xfce libexo-1-0 libexo-common libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfconf-0-2 orage tango-icon-theme thunar thunar-data thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4 xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-utils xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xfwm4-themes
```

Will remove everything related with xfce4 in your computer. You will need to install aptitude first if you haven't:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try aptitude.

Install it: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Maybe you will have first to install again xfce4: `sudo aptitude install xfce4`

Now purge it: `sudo aptitude purge xfce4`

---

ps.: I've never installed xfce4 but the command `apt-cache search xfce4` also gives me [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/680205/) output.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but startx still launches xfce

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Type 'sudo apt-get remove --purge xfce4. Yes,  you've akready done this,  but a few extra seconds involved  won't hurt...  much.

Then type 'find xfce4' (as rarely, if ever, everything IS actually removed)

Then manually delete anything found.

Then type 'sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove, this, in most cases removes any no longer needed dependencies.

For some reason Ubuntu expecting that you will at some future point reinstall a program, it leaves behind some of the configuration files, which in many cases causes problems later.

This is the quickest way that I know of, there are indubitably better ways available,  but this method works for me,  which, is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .xfce.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge xfce*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .xfce.   filters, so that only packages with keyword xfce within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```