# How to deal with problems with Xfce?

Tags: 12.04, xfce, session

I am using Xfce 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04. Any choice of Desktop Environment starts Xfce. I don't get any Splash Screen nor Xfce session selector nor WiFi icon, neither the option to restart/shutdown.

Last night I closed the session normally and today I found many problems:

- No matter whether I try to start session on Unity, GNOME, Gnome-Classic, MATE, etc, it 
  always start Xfce. It doesn't even show the Xfce session selector nor the splash screen.
- It doesn't start the `freemeteo` screenlet.
- `Orage` starts up automatically.
- WiFi icon is missing (but I'm connected to the net).
- On the user menu, "Suspend" and "Shut Down" are greyed out.
- "Logout" is enabled, but when I click on it, it gives me the following error:

  > The name org.xfce.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

**EDIT:** The last package I had installed before this started was `xfce4-utils`. I can't open Synaptic Package Manager to uninstall it or to find broken packages. Synaptic doesn't start.

I don't know what to do. I'm still new to Xfce. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to remove `Xfce`. Run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xfce4-utils
```

`purge` option causes `apt` to remove not only a package but also the saved settings.

Also try (but without `purge`):

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce
```

See this question [Why removing the xfce4 package doesn't remove the XFCE desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59640/how-can-i-completely-remove-xfce4-when-apt-get-remove-purge-doesnt-work) for more details on how to do that.