# Firefox's "Open folder" opens Gwenview

Tags: 12.04, firefox, mime-type

Upgrading to 12.04 caused some problems to my Firefox.
It seems like that Firefox doesn't know how to handle downloads.

After some researches, I've found this solution :
[Kubuntu 12.04 Firefox and Rekong don't know how to open downloaded files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112194/kubuntu-12-04-firefox-and-rekong-dont-know-how-to-open-downloaded-files)

but it still doesn't work as it should, in fact it opens my mp3 with Audacity and not with the default player.

But the worst thing is that "Open folder" opens Gwenview instead of Dolphin!

Suggestions?

Comment: The answer from elpd worked for me.

Comment: This issue is still relevant in Kubuntu 14.10 and the answer below by @elpd still works.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/55174/47206

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox application associations not working in the 'Downloads' window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20015/firefox-application-associations-not-working-in-the-downloads-window)

Answer (score 20):

On Kde, a different approach not involving direct editing. Took it from the [link](https://forums.mageia.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2339) Miguel Aguayo gave in his answer. Someone attached that answer at the bottom in 2014.

1. Go to System Settings.
2. Open File Associations.
3. Go to Inode -> Directory
4. Remove Gwenview from the Application preference order list. Press Apply.
5. Optionally, you can add again Gwenview and make it at the bottom of the list of preferences.

Comment: +1 for using UI instead of editing files. This worked for me even though Gwenview was initially already last option. Removing it fixed Firefox and adding it back did not break it.

Comment: This issue is still relevant in Kubuntu 14.10 and the answer still works so thanks @elpd.

Comment: Still relevant in Kubuntu 15.04, and still works.

Comment: also relevant in Kubuntu 18.04, it worked for me and also Gwenview was already last option.

Comment: Also relevant for XFCE4 where Firefox was using VSCode to open folder instead of Thunar

Comment: With KDE Plasma5 the navigation path is 'System Settings'->'Applications'->'File Associations'->'inode'->'directory'

Answer (score 4):

This [**link**](https://forums.mageia.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2339) worked for me.

In short, in the file `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` add these lines:

```
[Added Associations]

x-directory/normal=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-filelight.desktop;kde4-cervisia.desktop;

[Default Applications]

inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-filelight.desktop;kde4-cervisia.desktop;
x-directory/normal=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've also encountered this problem. Rather than copy-pasting a blob of text which I don't understand, I tried to figure out which parts of the suggested answer are useful.

1. Edit the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
2. Append either of the following lines (at the `[Added Associations]` section):

   ```
   x-directory/normal=kde4-dolphin.desktop;
   inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;
   ```
3. Save and Firefox will use Dolphin from now on.

You do not need both lines. Whichever comes last defines the file browser to be opened.

This configuration file maps a mime-type to a `.desktop` file, which defines which application ought to open the file. After the mime-type, a semicolon-separated list of possible applications is listed. The left-most application has the highest priority, the rightmost file has the lowest (fallback) priority.

Those `*.desktop` files are located at `/usr/share/applications/`.
The `kde-*.desktop` files are located at the subdirectory `/usr/share/applications/kde4/`.
( `/usr/share/applications/kde4/dolphin.desktop` , for example )

Answer (score 0):

[elpddev's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/504467/527764) was right but outdated.

If you use Kubuntu or Plasma desktop, open **System Settings** and open **Applications** under **Personalization**. Under **Default Applications**, click **File Manager** and select **Files** or any other file manager you want. You can here change default terminal too which was driving me nuts.

Comment: Tried this before looking for a solution on the internet. Dolphin was set as default but still did not fire up when I used the "open folder" option in transmission (the torrent client).