# How do I change which app Transmission uses on the "open folder" option?

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent, transmission, dolphin

When I right click on a torrent and use the "open folder" option on the drop-down it automatically opens in ranger (a terminal file browser) when I want it to open in the Dolphin file manager. When I uninstalled ranger and then repeat this action, it opens the folder in Gwenview. The thing is that Dolphin is already my default file manager. How do I fix this so Transmission knows to automatically open the folder in Dolphin?

Comment: some programs have the nasty habit of taking over the "open folder" action in downloading applications (especially internet browsers). What happens when you do the same in your browser? https://askubuntu.com/questions/131695/firefoxs-open-folder-opens-gwenview , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296418/32012

Comment: If I use "Open Containing Folder" from the downloads button on Firefox it views the folder in Dolphin

Answer (score 1):

1. From the Applications menu, open **MIME Type Editor**
2. Search for **inode**
3. Change **"inode/directory"** to your preferred file manager.

From now on **Transmission** will use your chosen file manager.