# Default file manager changed, can't change back

Tags: 11.04, gnome, google-chrome, default, filemanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chromium “Show in Folder” opens in text editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39769/chromium-show-in-folder-opens-in-text-editor)

(Using ubuntu 11.04)

I tried to open a torrent file in chrome, and it asked for my default application, so I clicked Transmission, and then I got an error: "Failed to execute default file manager, Failed to execute child process "transmission" (No such file or directory)."

Now if I click on any shortcut on the unity bar, such as the trash folder or the icon for my portable hard drive, I get this error, as well as with any download or folder from chrome or firefox. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this, as there seems to be no easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can answer this with an answer I posted a while back here [Chromium "Show in Folder" opens in text editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39769/chromium-show-in-folder-opens-in-text-editor)
 (That would make this a duplicate so it might get closed ;) )

In `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` there is a list of files to be opend by an application. Have a look with `more ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and check if you can find something weird here. You can use vi or gedit to edit this file.

But there is also a command **mimeopen** that allows you to alter what program should open what file (and that updates the file I mentioned before). It will 'guess' what would be the most logical option based on the file you feed it.

```
mimeopen -d /home/{your_name}/Documents
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Open Folder  (nautilus-folder-handler)
    2) Other...

mimeopen -d \[Mazui\]_Ore_No_Imouto_-_14_\[SD\]\[7EA51F50\].mkv 
Please choose a default application for files of type video/x-matroska

    1) Enqueue in SMPlayer  (smplayer_enqueue)
    2) Movie Player  (totem)
    3) SMPlayer  (smplayer)
    4) Banshee  (banshee)
    5) VLC media player  (vlc)
    6) Other...
```

Same works for a torrent file and any other file.

Maybe you already know this but if you can not get to command line use control-alt-f1 and log in with your sudo user account and password. control-alt-f7 gets you back to your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Open up a terminal and type:

gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications

Find "File Manager" and right-click on it. Choose "Properties." Under the "Basic" tab, change "Command" to "nautilus".

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file: `~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache`, and it should reset your file manager.

Comment: It seems there is no ../share/mime, however there is ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache and /mimeapps.list, should I remove one of those?

Comment: Do not delete it please. When someone talks about a file do `locate mime.cache` (change mime.cache to what you want to search) and you will get the location: `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache` You can rename this to mime.cache.old and then remove mime.cache. If things go wild due to deleting something you can use the *old version back to the original! (always try to use the safest option ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind: good catch, I only just saw his comment :)!

Comment: I've deleted it (after backing it up) and restarted my pc, but the problem is still there (seems nothing has changed)

Comment: I messed up too! I do not have a mimelist.cache. That would suggest I have nothing there yet (due to never changing a mimetype!) so ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache should be safe to remove and my other comment was not accurate! :)

Comment: @user16171: please try my answer too; it helped the person in the other topic so it might help you too!

Comment: I've tried deleting that too now, but nothing's happened. I've also tried opening folders and other filetypes in nautilus and on the desktop itself, it seems the problem only occurs when opening something from chrome or in the unity launcher, it may not have anything to do with mimetypes. Also, the mime cache file in /usr/share had some data in it, while the second one only contained one line ("[mime]") so I dont' know if that's responsible.

Comment: @user16171: the fix I listed here usually works, so I guess you must have affected something else :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it back with gconf:

```
gconftool --set "/desktop/gnome/applications/component_viewer/exec" --type string "nautilus %s"
```

Note: you should replace nautilus with na exec name of you preferred file manager.