# Clicking on a folder in docky opens banshee not nautilus

Tags: banshee, docky, directory

Somehow the action for opening folders has got confused.

I think at some point I tried to open a folder with banshee, and now when I try to open a folder, it always ends up in banshee.

This is from the "places" menu, and docky.

I'm not sure where to change this behaviour, and can't get the default behaviour back, without uninstalling banshee.

Any ideas..?

e: After uninstalling and installing banshee again, the behaviour comes back, so there must be something editable somewhere that is causing this.

(maverick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the problems like these relate to mimetypes. There is a file in your home that stores what filetype needs to be opend by what program. Have a look at my reply here: [Default file manager changed, can't change back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40421/default-file-manager-changed-cant-change-back) and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution would be to open Nautilus:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Type  *nautilus*  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Over any directory folder, press the **right-mouse-button**
- Select "Open with another app.."
- Right click on Banshee
- Click forget association

This should be enough.