# Smart SVN opens instead of Nautilus when click on a file system folder in dash or wherever under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, directory

The problem is that when I click on a folder in dash or in cairo-dock I get Smart SVN up instead of Nautilus.

How to resolve this annoying thing?

I tried those suggestions but with no success.

- [Clicking on a folder in docky opens banshee not nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40987/clicking-on-a-folder-in-docky-opens-banshee-not-nautilus)
- [Default file manager changed, can't change back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40421/default-file-manager-changed-cant-change-back)

I deleted `~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache` and also tried

> gconftool --set "/desktop/gnome/applications/component_viewer/exec" --type string "nautilus %s"

But Smart SVN is still associated with the folders.

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` and comment this section:

```
x-directory/normal assignment in [Default Applications]
```

Like this:

```
[Default Applications]
#x-directory/normal=smartsvn-9_2.desktop
```

This annoying behavior is gone.